# Questions about protected areas' effectiveness assessment

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am researching about the protected areas' effectiveness assessment,
My question is for example one protected area is built in year 2001, with MOD13Q1 data available since year 2000, how to better translate the  effectiveness of 'protected area'? I know one of the method can be done that is the comparative analysis of 'before protected' and 'after protected', like: 2000-2001----before protected, 2001-2019: after protected, but for 'before protected' the length of time is just one year and this result is not objective enough. I want to know is there any good solutions to resolve this problem of the extremely short former period: 'before protected', is there any way or mainstream method to substitute this unreliable method?

Comment: You could use the Landsat time series starting with Landsat 5 in 1985 instead of MODIS. If temporal density isn't as important that should work just as well.

Comment: @JonasV I have a protected area which is built in year1985, now I have the landsat yearly composite data from year 1984 to year 2020, but this protected area is hard to convince it's protection because 'before protected' is still with just one year difference.

Comment: I would perform a time series analysis on both the Landsat and the MOD13Q1 data.  Is there a structural break in the landsat data before and after protection was enabled?   Was it stationary before 2001 and trend-stationary after 2001?  Is the MOD13Q1 trend-stationary?

Comment: @jgm_GIS I will compare the MOD13Q1 data with the Landsat time series data when they share the same overlapping time period to compare their trend. My question is that the time series seem not long enough for some protected area for analysis. Maybe your advice is that for the 2001 protected area I can use landsat for trend analysis and for 2001-2020 I can use both Landsat and MOD13Q1. I am also considering another break time like maybe 'the important turning point or something', but what do you mean the 'structural break' here?

Comment: Structural break in time series: 
httpss://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break#:~:text=In%20econometrics%20and%20statistics%2C%20a,of%20the%20model%20in%20general.

Comment: @jgm_GIS Thankyou sir, but here these kinds of methods are used for detecting the unknown break point if I didn't get you wrong, you mean when I can't use 'before and after' judgement, it's better to throw all the natural reserves with one universal algorithm for detecting the break point in time series by data's statistical feature?

Comment: They work with known break points.  See the first subsection in the link I sent above:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break#A_single_break_in_mean_with_a_known_breakpoint